# How to check arguments without throwing exception?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has the nice functions `check`, `require` and `assert`. All of these allow me to easily check function arguments for validity and throw an exception if they are not valid. this is meant to make the checks more readable in a single line instead of implementing it with an if block over three lines.

However what if I do not want to throw an exception for invalid arguments but instead I just want to log something and then return? What if my code is at this point still in a valid state if I just return from this function? On one hand I look for a neater way than an if experession but I also specifically have problems with naming such a condition. For example:

```
if (!isArgumentValid(arg)) {
    return
}
```

Here it is unclear whether the `isArgumentValid` function also does the logging. So maybe better some name that indicates that the function actually handles the argument problem. Like `handleInvalidArgument`. But now it is no longer a question and it is unclear what the return value indicates. Does `true` mean the argument was valid or it was invalid and got handled?

What are the common practices here?

Comment: I would probably use exit custom codes there, that is why they exist more or less. Just a thing to remember, `0` means it worked fine, `negative` numbers are system generated, and `positive` numbers between `1-127` are user defined, and `128-255` are usually left for unix systems (they are actually negative if you think of them as 8-bit signed binary, or twos complement, so system generated again)

Comment: IMO, “handle” is a trap verb for method names. Meaningless if you think about it.

Comment: You examples like `require` don’t perform any validation. They just take a Boolean. Does this hypothetical function do nothing but show a generic log message if false is passed to it?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes handle is not good. I was also considering `ensureArgumentValid`. But similarly difficult to judge the return value.
About `require` I just listed it because it is part of the typical throw functions. I could make something like a require function that has another parameter next to the boolean, that then is logged in the message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of common practices as such for this, I'm afraid; exceptions seem to be much more common.  (Those can either be logged where they're caught, or you can use a custom exception which logs at construction.)

Ideally, the check function would cause the caller to return immediately — but although Kotlin does have non-local returns, this particular case seems to be impossible.  So it will have to return some value for the caller to check.  Since the caller will simply be checking whether to return, a simple boolean return value seems most suitable.

For readability, the function name should indicate the meaning of a ‘true’ return value.  (We'd also like it to indicate that the function does some logging, too; but I can't see how to do that without it becoming unmanageable.  However, most other functions that do incidental logging don't mention it in their names, so I think we'd be justified in dispensing with it here.)

All of which suggests a function name like `isInvalidArgument()` or `isNotValidArgument()`.  You could call it as:

```
if (isNotValidArgument(arg))
    return
```

For a check that's on a single value (especially if it's not a common type), it might be more readable as an extension function, which you could call as:

```
if (arg.isNotValidArgument())
    return
```

Of course, you'd pick a name which was more specific to the argument being checked or the check being done, where that made sense — e.g. `isNotValidPhoneNumber()`.

(There's precedent for this form in the standard library, with extension methods such as [`isNotEmpty()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-not-empty.html).)

The most obvious alternative would be to flip the sense of the function, like `isValidArgument()`, which would make it slightly clearer.  However, the caller would then need to invert it, like `if (!isValidArgument(arg))`, which is harder to read; and `!` is easy to miss, risking misunderstanding and potential bugs.  (It's even less worse with an extension function, like `if (!arg.isValidArgument())`.)  So I probably wouldn't recommend that.